# Transmit params to meta subclass of an abstract model

Tags: django

**Django 2.2.3**

How can I transmit a param to Meta inner class of an abstract model?

My efforts:

```
class GeneralUtmAbstract(models.Model):
    where = ""

    class Meta:
        def __init__(self):
            self.verbose_name_plural = "General UTM-labels: {}".format(GeneralUtmAbstract.where)
            self.verbose_name = verbose_name_plural

class GeneralUtm(GeneralUtmAbstract):
    where = "Both"

class BingUtm(GeneralUtmAbstract):
    where = "Bing"

class GoogleUtm(GeneralUtmAbstract):
    where = "Google"
```

My code doesn't raise any errors. But verbose names just don't show as planned. I get "general utm" instead of "General UTM-labels: both".

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the model abstract, and then decide which row of `where` will be shown as the table's name (why you'd do this, I can't fathom):

```
class GeneralUtmAbstract(models.Model):
    where = ""

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        verbose_name_plural = "General UTM-labels" + str(GeneralUtmAbstract.objects.filter(where=something)
```

If the idea is to logically segregate objects within the same model/table, consider using a proxy model; see [here](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/using-proxy-models-customize-django-admin/)